# Training CNN: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to train a model with the following layers:

```py
embedding_dim = 80

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 120, 3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(padding='same'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(padding='same'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512,  2, strides=(2, 4), activation='relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512,  3, activation='relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(add_timing_signal_nd))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(embedding_dim))
```

After, I run

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, reduction='none'), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(image_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=val_dataset)
```

I get the following error

```sh
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'conv2d_2/bias:0', 'conv2d_3/kernel:0', 'conv2d_3/bias:0', 'conv2d_4/kernel:0', 'conv2d_4/bias:0', 'conv2d_5/kernel:0', 'conv2d_5/bias:0', 'conv2d_6/kernel:0', 'conv2d_6/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0'].
```

For further context, `add_timing_signa_nd` is defined as the following

```py
def add_timing_signal_nd(x, min_timescale=1.0, max_timescale=1.0e4):
    """
    Args:
        x: a Tensor with shape [batch, d1 ... dn, channels]
        min_timescale: a float
        max_timescale: a float
    Returns:
        a Tensor the same shape as x.
    """
    static_shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
    num_dims = len(static_shape) - 2
    channels = tf.shape(x)[-1]
    num_timescales = channels // (num_dims * 2)
    log_timescale_increment = (
            math.log(float(max_timescale) / float(min_timescale)) /
            (tf.cast(num_timescales, dtype=tf.float32) - 1))
    inv_timescales = min_timescale * tf.exp(
            tf.cast(tf.range(num_timescales), dtype=tf.float32) * -log_timescale_increment)
    for dim in xrange(num_dims):
        length = tf.shape(x)[dim + 1]
        position = tf.cast(tf.range(length), dtype=tf.float32)
        scaled_time = tf.expand_dims(position, 1) * tf.expand_dims(
                inv_timescales, 0)
        signal = tf.concat([tf.sin(scaled_time), tf.cos(scaled_time)], axis=1)
        prepad = dim * 2 * num_timescales
        postpad = channels - (dim + 1) * 2 * num_timescales
        signal = tf.pad(signal, [[0, 0], [prepad, postpad]])
        for _ in xrange(1 + dim):
            signal = tf.expand_dims(signal, 0)
        for _ in xrange(num_dims - 1 - dim):
            signal = tf.expand_dims(signal, -2)
        x += signal
    return x
```

If it helps by input sizes are the following

```
(3, 50, 120, 3)
(3, 50, 120, 3)
(3, 50, 120, 3)
(1, 50, 120, 3)
```

Also, I'm planning to extract the weights after training to use them in another problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's in `add_timing_signal_nd` can you add that?

Comment: Hi @thushv89, I've updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the image_dataset or val_dataset is not proper. Follow your code, I simulated some data（include labels） to train and it could run properly.

```
image_dataset = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (3000, 50, 120, 3))
image_dataset_y = np.random.uniform(0, embedding_dim, (3000,)).astype(np.int)
val_dataset = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (300, 50, 120, 3))
val_dataset_y = np.random.uniform(0, embedding_dim, (300,)).astype(np.int)
model.fit(image_dataset, image_dataset_y , batch_size=30, epochs=10, validation_data=(val_dataset, val_dataset_y))
```